# Node.js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

'I wanted to get a response through the form I created with my app.js using node.js and express.js I created the `.get` to connect my html file to the app and I used the `.post` to pass my response to the server so I was trying to get the response of the form in the backend but all I was an error that says `'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` ' Here is my node and express code.'

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const firstName = req.bodyParser.fName;
  const lastName =  req.bodyParser.lName;
  const email = req.bodyParser.eMail;

  console.log(firstName, lastName, email);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

'Below is my html code used in case you anyone want to see the form'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Newsletter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="Fist Name" required autofocus>
      <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
      <input type="email" name="eMail" placeholder="Email" required>

      <button type="submit">submit</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `req.body` instead of `req.bodyParser` in the variable assignments

Comment: Thank you so much @RonB. the solution you provided worked perfectly. 